# How do I access a network location from my MS-DOS 6 Virtual Machine?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, file-sharing, ms-dos

Maybe it's a question that's more appropriated on ServerFault.  But here is my problem:

I have a Virtual Machine runing MS-DOS 6.22 and I would like to access some file on the Network.  I keep being on A: and cannot switch to another drive.

I'm not really used to DOS, and might be doing someting wrong.
Can someone help me and tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add drivers for your network card, and specific configuration. This doesn't work 'automagically' like it *sometimes* does on windows.

[Here's](http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/library/network/dostcpip.htm) a nice explanation on how to enable TCP/IP in DOS.

Maybe an easier solution: You could also boot the virtual machine with [The Universal TCP/IP Network Boot Disk](http://www.netbootdisk.com/), which should enable network support by default.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try this out thanks. And how can I work an another drive? It keeps telling me "Not ready reading drive B", or not even finding them. I suppose A is the floppy, am I wrong?

Comment: You should have a C drive as well, at least if you put a hard drive in your virtual machine. Of course you would have to format it before dos can do anything with it (format c:).

Comment: Nothing seems to work the right way... I'll try again later. Problem is I don't have a floppy disk drive...

Comment: You can insert a floppy disk image in the "virtual floppy disk drive" no?

Comment: Ok, that's done. Now how can I access the network? It says the driver is runing correctely, but I cant ping a computer on the network.

Comment: I suppose ping requests are blocked by the firewall... You should be able to map a drive letter to a network drive using the `net use x: \\pcname\sharename` command.

Comment: Doesn't work either. "Bad command or file name".I even tried with drives maped on my XP machine. Same problem.

Comment: That means the `net` command is not available. Can you describe what you have done exactly. Have you booted with the disk? The `net` command should then be available from a:\

Comment: I mounted Netdisk (as ISO) on a virtual floppy on the machine (A:). I type the command net use T: \\SERVER1\FILE1.

Comment: Have you actually booted from that disk? do you see a `net.exe` on that disk?